# How to Implement DOM Data Binding in DART lang

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer, angular-dart, dart-html

I do not want to re-invite the wheel of Angular or Polymer, but want to understand how the the data binding happen and how the html file use double curly braces {{ ... }} to contain Angular expressions.

How the below code is understood and executed!

```
Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name">
<h3>Hello {{name}}!</h3>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Polymer this is done by polymer_expressions package https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/polymer_expressions.
In Angular.dart this is done by Angular code during HTML 'compiling'.